# Angular ng-repeat and ajax changes between 1.0.8 and 1.2.7

Tags: ajax, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Happy new year!

There is one thing that I can't get, and i would appreciate if you help me.
What changed in ng-repeat and ajax logic between 1.0.8 and 1.2.7 Angular versions? I checked [changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) but didn't found anything helpful.

I have node.js site with angular and mongodb DB. Logic on node.js side returns list of some objects in json via ajax. Also I use ngRoute.

My problem is that this code works fine in angular 1.0.8 version. But if I update to the latest 1.2.7, then it doesn't work. Part of template with div Search is displayed fine, but there is no divs that should be produced by ng-repeats. There is no any errors in browser console. Json response returns fine via Ajax.

I've tried to reuse code from [Angular ng-repeat sample](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angRepeat) in my template and it works fine for me in Angular 1.2.7. But my code doesn't work.

I have such template code defined in another html file:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
    <div>
        Search
        <input type="text" ng-enter="updateQuery()" ng-model="query"/>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <!-- these divs with ng-repeat aren't rendered-->
        <div>
            <div class="btn-group filter-buttons" ng-repeat="n in [] | range:recipes.pageCount">
                <a class="btn btn-default" ng-class="{active: n==recipes.pageNumber}" href="#/list/{{n}}/{{query}}">{{ n }}</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4" ng-repeat="recipe in recipes.items">
            <h2>Recipe <a class="btn-details btn btn-default" href="#/details/{{recipe._id}}">Details »</a></h2>
            <img class="recipe-preview" ng-repeat="hash in recipe.MappedPhotos" src="/picture/{{hash}}"/>
            <p> {{ recipe.Description | truncate:250 }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then i have such factory for ajax:

```
app.factory('recipeService', function($http) {
    return {
        getRecipes: function(pageNumber) {
            var url = '/api/recipe/?pageNumber=' + pageNumber;
            return $http.get(url).then(function(result) {
                    // this method called fine and returns correct result
                    return result.data;
                });
        }
    }
});
```

And such angular controller:

```
app.controller('RecipesListCtrl', function($scope, recipeService, $routeParams, $location) {

    $scope.pageNumber = !$routeParams.pageId ? 1 : $routeParams.pageId;

    $scope.updatePage = function(n){
        $scope.recipes = recipeService.getRecipes(n);
    };

    $scope.updatePage($scope.pageNumber);
});
```

Here is my ajax request\response:

Request:

```
GET http://localhost:3001/api/recipe/?pageNumber=1 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3001
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Pragma: no-cache
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://localhost:3001/
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 54057
ETag: "1790659200"
Date: Sat, 04 Jan 2014 18:08:26 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

{
  "items": [
    // some data here
  ],
  "pageNumber": "1",
  "pageSize": 20,
  "pageCount": 55
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: `ng-repeat="n in [] | range:recipes.pageCount"` ????

Comment: Yes, it my custom filter, that just returns array of integers for specified size. So, i can make some kind of paging based on page count.

Comment: I have post my answer below for simple solution. have you like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use promises directly in angular templates anymore. Instead, you must use an actual array. See http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#templates-no-longer-automatically-unwrap-promises:

Before:

```
$scope.foo = $http({method: 'GET', url: '/someUrl'});

<p>{{foo}}</p>
```

After:

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: '/someUrl'})
  .success(function(data) {
    $scope.foo = data;
  });

<p>{{foo}}</p>
```

This feature has been deprecated. If absolutely needed, it can be reenabled for now via the $parseProvider.unwrapPromises(true) API.

Comment: Big thank you for the answer! I've removed promises, and subscribed to success method, and updated $scope.recipes variable here, and how it works fine for me. 

Strange that they deprecated it, as promises were useful for such cases and make code looks simpler.